# Electron click() handler unknown JS Syntax

Tags: javascript, electron

I am quite new to JavaScript but I stumbled across some unfamiliar syntax when looking at a click handler in Electron JS:

```
click() {createWindow();}
```

I see a function object followed by another object and a syntax that reminds me of an if-statement in JS

```
if (condition) { do this }
```

How can I write a function like that to reproduce the behavior and how can I understand this syntax ...? Maybe someone knows the name of this or is able to point me to a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is standard JavaScript syntax for a function (or method).  A more familiar syntax would be:

```
click() {
  createWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the syntax used when [defining methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) on a JavaScript object.